# Checking if an account is valid in Django

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create some validation logic to my views. In order to not repeat myself, I'd like to have the validation logic in a single function, which can then be called by other view functions. The validation function is called `check_if_account_valid`. However, it looks like the `HttpResponseRedirect`s which are embedded in the validation function are not being called -- the `subscription_status` check works ('Subscription status is lapsed' is printed out), but the redirect does not happen.

How can I have a view that executes some validation logic when each view is called? Is there a reason you can't call a view from within another view? Is there a better way of doing this?

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):

    SUBSCRIPTION_CHOICES = (
        ('Dev Account', 'Dev Account for Testing'),
        ('15 day trial', '15 day trial'),
        ('Paid', 'Paid account - payment up to date'),
        ('Lapsed', 'Paid account - payment lapsed'),
        ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
        )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscription_status = models.CharField(choices=SUBSCRIPTION_CHOICES, default='15 day trial',
                                            max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def check_if_account_valid(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        subscription_status = request.user.account.subscription_status
        date_created = request.user.account.date_created
        if subscription_status == '15 day trial':
            localtz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Lisbon')
            now_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            now_datetime_loc = localtz.localize(now_datetime)
            # check if trial is up
            if (date_created - now_datetime_loc) < datetime.timedelta(days=15):
                pass
            # if it is up, do nothing
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscription/trial_ended/')
        elif subscription_status == 'Paid':
            pass
        elif subscription_status == 'Lapsed':
            print('Subscription status is lapsed')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscription/lapsed/')
        elif subscription_status == 'Inactive':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscription/inactive/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

def home(request):
    check_if_account_valid(request)
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

> Django==1.8.4

Comment: Why have you created a `check_if_account_valid` view? You could just have made it a simple function instead!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are returning `HttpResponseRedirect` from `check_if_account_valid` to `home` but then not doing anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't return your response. To get your approach to work, you might want to change it to this:

```
def check_if_account_valid(request, next_view):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        subscription_status = request.user.account.subscription_status
        date_created = request.user.account.date_created
        if subscription_status == '15 day trial':
            localtz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Lisbon')
            now_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            now_datetime_loc = localtz.localize(now_datetime)
            # check if trial is up
            if (date_created - now_datetime_loc) < datetime.timedelta(days=15):
                pass
            # if it is up, do nothing
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscription/trial_ended/')
        elif subscription_status == 'Paid':
            pass
        elif subscription_status == 'Lapsed':
            print('Subscription status is lapsed')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscription/lapsed/')
        elif subscription_status == 'Inactive':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscription/inactive/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

    return next_view
```

And then call your view like this:

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    next_view = render(request, 'home.html', context)
    return check_if_account_valid(request, next_view)
```

A better (more django-like) approach might be to switch to [ClassBased View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/), create a [Mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) in which the `check_if_account_valid` is called in the [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) methdod.

Comment: Creating a mixin for a CBV is fine, but it's not the only Django-like approach. Another option is to stick with a function-based view and create a decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Your `check_if_account_valid` function returns an `HTTPResponse` but then your `home` view doesn't do anything with it.

For the code to work, you would have to return the response

```
def home(request):
    return check_if_account_valid(request)
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

But that would *always* return, which you don't want for valid accounts. So you would need to add a check like the following:

```
def home(request):
    response = check_if_account_valid(request)
    if response is not None:
        return response
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

This works, but isn't very tidy. A better approach would be to make `check_if_account` a decorator. Django uses this approach for decorators like [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) and [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test). Then your view would simplify to:

```
@check_if_account_valid
def home(request):
```